# redux-form V6 custom component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want to create custom component for redux-form V6. It looks like buttons switcher.

**component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ButtonSwitcher extends Component{
// props.buttons [{text: "Btn Text", value: "BtnValue"}]
  render (){
    return (
      <div className="btn-group" style={{verticalAlign: 'top'}}>
        {this.props.buttons.map((button, index)=>(
          <a href="#" key={index} onClick={this.props.onChange} className={(this.props.value === button.value) ? 'active btn btn-default' : 'btn btn-default'}>{button.text}</a>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I use this component in my form:

```
const renderButtonSwitcher = props => {
  return (
    <ButtonSwitcher value={props.input.value} onChange={props.input.onChange} buttons={props.data} />
  )
};

<Field name="PODType" component={renderButtonSwitcher} data={[{text: '%', value: 'percent'}, {text: '$', value: 'amount'}]} />
```

How i can get selected button value?
I can't find any advanced examples from redux-form V6

```
onSubmit(data) {
  console.log("onSubmit", data);
}
```

`onSubmit` showing empty data object

Answer (score 5):

I find the solution

Now my component looks:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ButtonSwitcher extends Component{
  // props.buttons [{text: "Btn Text", value: "BtnValue"}]

  onClick(value){
    this.props.onChange(value);
  }

  render (){
    return (
      <div className="btn-group" style={{verticalAlign: 'top'}}>
        {this.props.buttons.map((button, index)=>(
          <a href="#" key={index} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, button.value)} className={(this.props.value === button.value) ? 'active btn btn-default' : 'btn btn-default'}>{button.text}</a>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Usage in form component:

```
const renderButtonSwitcher = props => {
      return (
        <ButtonSwitcher {...props.input} buttons={props.data} />
      )
    };

<Field name="PODType" component={renderButtonSwitcher} data={[{text: '%', value: 'percent'}, {text: '₽', value: 'amount'}]} />
```

I find [this discussion](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/277) and that gives me some ideas

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing that is not the way redux-form works. The `<Field />` Component is a wrapper for all the various html form fields like `<input />`, `<textarea />` and so on.

Those fields have a `name` and `value` property which is used in Forms and by redux-form, too.

You are rendering `<a />`, which are simple links, so redux-form cannot get/set their values.

To get values out of those links, you need to work around, probably using a hidden field, which is updated when such a link is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

After referring to below link I got some idea.

https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/faq/customcomponent.md/

I found a workaround as below:

`<Field name="customCompValue" component={props => {
              props.input.onChange(newValueOfCustomComponent)
              return <MyCustomComponent someProp={props.input.value} />
 }} />`

After this, I was able to get the value of custom component along with other fields values in the form.